# Hide Navigation Bar in Firefox using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am using Selenium to automate some activities. My code is

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxDriverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

This opens firefox and navigates me to Google. But I want to open firefox with navigation bar hidden. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Full screen is the equivalent of pressing F11 on your browser and removes the navigation bar.

```
driver.Manage().Window.FullScreen();
```

[Update 1] - Seems to only work for chrome but if you want no header bar try this:

```
options.AddArguments("--app=https://google.co.uk");
```

[Update 2] - Different to the above, for Firefox and chrome, try kiosk mode:

```
options.AddArguments("--Kiosk=https://www.google.co.uk");
```

Firefox command line options available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

Comment: Yes. But it appears again once mouse touches top. Is it possible to hide it permanently?

Comment: I've seen it done. Just see if I can find the tag then il update the answer

Comment: updated - it only works in chrome, i'll see if i can find the same tag for firefox...